# How do I set my CPU governor on boot?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, linux-kernel, cpu, cpu-frequency

I'm running Linux Mint 19.2 with a custom kernel (5.4.2-blackbox) and I'm trying to set my CPU governor to "performance" on boot. I have an i7 7700k and I tried disabling p-state with GRUB using `intel_pstate=disable`. I don't have Linux-Tools and can't seem to install it for some reason. I have tried putting `cpufreq-set -c 0 -r -g performance` (repeating to core 8) through rc.local, and I have tried running the same thing as a script in init.d. When I'm fully started up, the command works as expected, as do the scripts when I manually run them, but I want them to run on startup.

Answer (score 1):

In a dashboard, a add have the

Applet moniteur de changements de fréquence du processeur
1.22.1
Copyright © 2004 Carlos Garcia Campos
Copyright © 2012-2019 MATE developers

and when click on it, it show options :

[image: CPU Freq Options]